# IcCube - accessing a chart at runtime

Tags: javascript, iccube

We would like to write a piece of (javascript-)code, that automatically runs in every report and that manipulates all of our charts. Doing so we would like to add tooltips with descriptions of our measures and dimensions and rename some of the measures.
The easiest way would be probably, to have our code manipulate the MDX-queries before the first load.

Is this - or something similar - possible with IcCube?

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit: do you mean server response transformation before rendering?

Comment: Either that, or an elegant way, to do this after rendering. But then probably it would have to run at every filtering etc...